# Highcharts stacked bar negative / positive total

Tags: highcharts, bar-chart, stacked

I have a stacked bar chart like this: http://jsfiddle.net/XFX5T/

I would like to know if it's possible to have the total of the negative + positive values as the stacked label.

if the total is positive, show the label at the top of the bar.
if the total is negative, show the label at the bottom of the bar.

The grapes column in the example would have 40 as label for instance.

Looked at the documentation but looks like there is nog default config setting for this.

```
stackLabels: {
   enabled: true,
   style: {
     fontWeight: 'bold',
     color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.textColor) || 'gray'
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can try with a stackLabels formatter. For example:

```
stackLabels: {
  formatter: function(){
    var sum = 0;
    var series = this.axis.series;

    for (var i in series){
      sum+=series[i].yData[this.x];
    }
    if (sum < 0 && this.isNegative || sum >= 0 && !this.isNegative)
      return sum;
  }
...
}
```

Comment: Perfect, I added an extra check to include only data that is visible:

`for (var i in series){
 if (series[i].visible)
 sum+=series[i].yData[this.x];
}`

Comment: superb, just what I was looking for

Answer (score 1):

One shortcoming of the accepted answer is that it won't work with grouped stacks, because you'll get the total for all stack series, not just the series in each group.

Here is a function that works for grouped stacks (not that it's pretty):

```
    function() {
        var stackItem = this;
        var allStacks = stackItem.axis.stacks;
        for (var key in allStacks) {
            if (allStacks[key][stackItem.x] == stackItem) {
                var oppositeKey = stackItem.isNegative ? key.slice(1) : '-' + key;
                var oppositeItem = allStacks[oppositeKey] && allStacks[oppositeKey][stackItem.x];
                if (oppositeItem === undefined) {
                    if (stackItem.total != 0.0) {
                        return Highcharts.numberFormat(stackItem.total, 0);
                    }
                } else {
                    var sum = stackItem.total + oppositeItem.total;
                    if (stackItem.isNegative ^ sum > 0) {
                        return Highcharts.numberFormat(sum, 0);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    };
```

N.b. I'm passing `this` from the formatter.

Here is a [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/kippr/ULwa3/4/).

Answer (score 0):

If you happen to come across this issue, but your x-axis uses `type: 'datetime'`, you can use this two-loop solution for the `stackLabels.formatter` to make it work:

```
formatter: function () {
    var sum = 0;
    var series = this.axis.series;

    for (var i = 0; i < series.length; i++){
        for(var j = 0; j < series[i].xData.length; j++) {
            if(series[i].xData[j] == this.x) {
                sum += series[i].yData[j];
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    if(sum < 0 && this.isNegative)
        return sum;
    else if(sum >= 0 && !this.isNegative)
        return sum;

     return;
}
```

As [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aTh7F/4/) demonstrates.